# RxJava2 make repeatable action and return result depending on if/else logic

Tags: android, redirect, observable, rx-java2, flatmap

Help me please to run rxJava code sample for android. Here is what I want to do:
I have a function, which gives me redirects one by one. I need to take that redirect (if it's not empty) and try to startActivity of external app with it. If redirect empty - I need to break and return some Result data with last redirect found. If this app started successfully - I need to return some Result object that tells that app have been opened, if not opened - I need to try to get next redirect. Here is code that I have:

```
public Observable<Result> getStartAppResult(String url, AppOpeningRule shopOpeningRule) {
    return getSingleHttpRedirectUrl(url, appOpeningRule)
            .flatMap(redirect -> {
                if(Strings.isNullOrEmpty(redirect)){
                    return isAppStarted(redirect, appOpeningRule.getPackageName());
                } else {
                    return getDataSourceWithParams(redirect);
                }
            })
            .flatMap(appStarted -> {
                if(appStarted){
                    return getDataSourceWithParams(redirect);
                } else {
                    return getSingleHttpRedirectUrl(url, appOpeningRule);
                }
            });
}


private ObservableSource<Result> getDataSourceWithParams(String finalUrl) {
    Result result = new Result(finalUrl, lastRedirectUrl);
    return Observable.just(result);
}

public Observable<Boolean> isAppStarted(String url, String appPackageName) {
    return Observable.create(emitter -> {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REQUIRE_NON_BROWSER);
        intent.setPackage(appPackageName);

        boolean hasActivityNotFoundException = false;
        try {
            context.startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException exception) {
            hasActivityNotFoundException = true;
        } finally {
            emitter.onNext(!hasActivityNotFoundException);
            emitter.onComplete();
        }
    });
}

private Observable<String> getSingleHttpRedirectUrl(String url,
                                                    final ShopOpeningRule appOpeningRule) {
    return httpService.goToWebSiteLink(url)
            .compose(rxTransformers.applyUnauthorizedHandlerCustomError())
            .onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> {
                if (throwable instanceof RetrofitException) {
                    RetrofitException error = (RetrofitException) throwable;
                    if (error.getKind() == Kind.HTTP) {
                        if (error.getHttpExceptionCode() >= REDIRECT_START && error.getHttpExceptionCode() <= REDIRECT_END) {
                            String redirectUrl = error.getResponse().headers().get(KEY_HEADER_REDIRECT_LOCATION);
                            if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(redirectUrl)) {
                                lastRedirectUrl = redirectUrl;
                                if (appOpeningRule.hasRedirectLinkPatterns()) {
                                    if (LinkParser.urlContainsPattern(redirectUrl, appOpeningRule.getRedirectLinkPatterns())) {
                                        String modifiedLink = LinkParser.modifyRedirectLinkIfNeeded(redirectUrl, shopOpeningRule);
                                        return Observable.just(modifiedLink);
                                    } else {
                                        return Observable.just(redirectUrl);
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    return Observable.just(redirectUrl);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return Observable.just("");
            });
}
```

Comment: The code is overly complex and I suggest to simplify it first which would make it easier for you to understand what's going on and why it might not work (you didn't mention what's not working).
1. Use RxJava 3 instead of RxJava 2 (and use Kotlin instead of Java...)
2. getDataSourceWithParams doesn't need to be an Observable, just make it a simple method returning a value
3. The same is true for isAppStarted. Just a regular method.
4. Once those are converted, the first flatmap converts to a simple map function
5. getSingleHttpRedirectUrl can be simplified to a Single

Comment: thanks, I'll try, but can't move to rxjava3 - we use 2version on our project now, the same with kotlin - need to convert all file in this case

Comment: moving to Kotlin is easy, the interoperability with Java is very good so you can just write above functions in Kotlin and leave the rest in Java, once you moved to Kotlin you don't want to go back

Comment: I am 6 month on Kotlin, but for me Java is still more logical)) But need to mention that I have 6 years of Java experience by my back)